# Confused about method definition: def req=(request)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I found this in Ryan Bates' railscast site, but not sure how it works.

```
#models/comment.rb
def req=(request)
    self.user_ip    = request.remote_ip
    self.user_agent = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    self.referrer   = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
end

#blogs_controller.rb
def create
    @blog = Blog.new(params[:blog])
    @blog.req = request
    if @blog.save
        ...
```

I see he is saving the user ip, user agent and referrer, but am confused with the `req=(request)` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build on [Karmen Blake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650763/please-explain-this-rails-method-to-me-like-im-a-little-kid/2650789#2650789) and [KandadaBoggu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650763/please-explain-this-rails-method-to-me-like-im-a-little-kid/2650796#2650796), the first method definition makes it so when this line is executed:

```
@blog.req = request
```

It's like doing this instead:

```
@blog.user_ip    = request.remote_ip
@blog.user_agent = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
@blog.referrer   = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```

It basically sets up a shortcut. It looks like you're just assigning a variable's value, but you're actually calling a method named `req=`, and the `request` object is the first (and only) parameter.

This works because, in Ruby, functions can be used with or without parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the user_ip, user_agent, referrer are part of comments db table, just like comment.title, comment.body etc/ so why use @blog.user_ip?

Answer (score 6):

That line defines a method called `req=`. The `=` character in the end makes it an assignment method.

This is a regular setter method:

```
def foo(para1)
  @foo = para1
end
```

The setter method can be re-written as an assignment method as follows:

```
def foo=(para1)
  @foo = para1
end
```

Difference between the two setter methods is in the invocation syntax.

Assignment setter:

```
a.foo=("bar")   #valid syntax
a.foo= ("bar")  #valid syntax
a.foo = ("bar") #valid syntax
a.foo= "bar"    #valid syntax
a.foo = "bar"   #valid syntax
```

Regular setter:

```
a.foo("bar")    #valid syntax
a.foo ("bar")   #valid syntax
a.fo o ("bar")  #invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def name=(new_name)
 @name = new_name
end

has the same functionality as:

def name(new_name)
 @name = new_name
end
```

However, when calling the methods you get a little nicer more natural looking statement using an assignment rather than argument passing.

```
person = Person.new
person.name = "John Doe"
```

vs.

```
person.name("John Doe")
```

Hope that helps.